# Failed to resolve project: Android library and Java library module dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm trying to create a project which includes an Android library and a Java library in Android Studio (3.1). The Java library depends on the Android library. Both are modules in my project like this:

```
MyProject    
|-android
|-java
```

Both appear in settings.gradle:

```
include ':android', ':java'
```

And the Java library depends on the Android library like this:

java (`build.gradle`):

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':android')
}
...
```

android (`build.gradle`):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...
```

When trying to sync the project I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to resolve: project::android

Why?

**P.S.** The other way around (Android depending on Java) works just fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First let's try to fix the build error. Let's run `./gradlew build --stacktrace` to see a more detailed output:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.component.AmbiguousConfigurationSelectionException:
>
> Cannot choose between the following configurations of project **:androidLibrary**:
>
> - debugApiElements
> - releaseApiElements

[AGP](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) is confused which variant to choose. After inspecting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45685318/1083957) answer, we can find how to overcome the issue:

```
implementation project(path: ':androidLibrary', configuration: 'default')
```

After trying to sync the project with that setup you'll see following output in console:

> Ignoring dependency of module **'androidLibrary'** on module **'javaLibrary'**. Java modules cannot depend on Android modules

Thus, seems like what you try to do is not supported by the plugin.
Refer to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46156056/1083957), where Nick Cardoso tries to clarify the case.

Comment: I thought it might not be supported. Unfortunately neither your answer nor the one you linked to provides any other way to solve the problem (I know the other answer lists 3 "solutions" but none of them actually solves the problem, they all suggest to do something else instead).

Comment: The point is - you cannot do what you want to do, that is not supported by Android Gradle Plugin. I cannot see how you can achieve that considering the limitation that exists.

Comment: brilliant answer!  Exactly the problem I had. Great explanation!